Use different decoders for different URL patterns in SecurityFilterChain for JWT auth
I have a security filter chain bean created to do the following:
 @Bean
 SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
         authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/health/check").permitAll()
             .requestMatchers("swagger-ui/**", "swagger-ui**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/v3/api-docs**").permitAll()
             .requestMatchers("/api/v2/**").authenticated())
             .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                  oauth2.jwt(jwt ->jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder()))
             )
             .cors(withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
    JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(env.getIssuerUri());
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(env.getIssuerUri());
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator());
    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

    return jwtDecoder;
}

I want to be able to use a separate decoder for different URL patterns. I tried the to use useFilterBefore:
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/health/check","swagger-ui/**", "swagger-ui**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/v3/api-docs**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter("/api/v2/pattern1", decoder1()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter("/api/v2/(?!pattern1)(.*)", decoder2()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .cors(withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}
// same definition of decoder used for decoder1 and decoder2 but with different audience

However, this doesn't yet use the oauth2ResourceServer part to use the passed decoder. I am looking for an elegant way to solve this.

create two filter chains, let them handle different url patterns

@Toerktumlare that seems to always return a 403

Then enable dubug logs and provide us with logs that show us the reason and update your code to show us how you implemented it. As that is the solution and its most likely your implementation that is faulty

I figured the issue. I was trying to use a single TokenValidator bean for both the decoders which was causing the issue.
